# Heap corruption detected (class method)

Tags: c++

By running this code I get "Heap corruption detected".

```
    E3Point E3Point::operator+(E3Point & t)
    {
    E3Point ret;
    ret.naziv = new char[strlen(naziv) + strlen(t.naziv) + 1];
    ret.naziv = strcat(naziv, t.naziv);
    ret.X = X + t.X;
    ret.Y = Y + t.Y;
    ret.Z = Z + t.Z;
    return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem as required here please.

Comment: [mcve] needed. In particular, we need to understand naziv and E3Point. Odds are that the error is in how you use `strcat`. Read up what that function does, and make sure that the array naziv points to is large enough to hold the result of that call.

Comment: You could reduce headaches and defects by using `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Remember, for `strlen` to work correctly, the character array needs to be terminated by `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3):

These two lines leads to ***two*** problems:

```
ret.naziv = new char[strlen(naziv) + strlen(t.naziv) + 1];
ret.naziv = strcat(naziv, t.naziv);
```

The first is that [`std::strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat) appends to the string provided by the first argument. And if you don't have enough memory allocated for it you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `strcat` writes out of bounds.

The second problem is that `strcat` returns the destination, which means you're effectively doing

```
ret.naziv = naziv;
```

and therefore lose the original pointer given by the previous `new[]`, which leads to a memory leak (and possible other problems).

The simple solution is to stop using old C-style null-terminated byte strings, and instead use `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
ret.naziv = strcat(naziv, t.naziv);
```

You are not copying the strings correctly. You are copying `t.naziv` into `this->naviz` instead of to `ret.naziv`. And then you are assigning the returned pointer to `ret.naviz`, leaking the memory you `new`'ed, and making both `ret.naviz` and `this->naziv` point at the same memory.

You need to use this instead:

```
strcpy(ret.naziv, naziv);
strcat(ret.naziv, t.naziv);
```

Alternatively:

```
int len = strlen(naziv);
...
strcpy(ret.naziv, naziv);
strcpy(ret.naziv+len, t.naziv);
```

Alternatively:

```
sprintf(ret.naziv, "%s%s", naziv, t.naziv);
```

Also, if you are not already doing so, make sure you follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), or you will run into other problems.

You really should not be managing memory manually at all. Let the standard library do it for you. All of these problems would go away if `naziv` were a `std::string` instead of a `char*`.